# Как сделать линию таблицы ровной?

Tags: c, вывод, форматирование

Я создал программу, результат которой должен выводиться в таблицу. Все линии конечной таблицы отрегулировал, но последняя вертикальная сбивается из-за того, что результатами некоторых вычислений получаются числа с двумя цифрами до запятой. Ума не приложу, как можно это исправить. Слышал, что можно сделать так, чтобы таблица формировалась автоматически, но нигде не нашел информации об этом

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float a = -M_PI, b = M_PI/2, h = 0, x = 0;
    float F1 = 0, F2 = 0, F3 = 0, i = 0;
    int n = 7;

    h = (b-a)/n;        // h = 0.673198

    printf(" _______________________________________________________________\n|\tSingle\t\tvariable\t\tfunctions\t|\n|---------------------------------------------------------------|\n|   Argument   |   9+COS(X)   |   SIN(X)COS(X)   |   14SIN(X)   |\n");


    for (i = 0; i<=n; i++)
        {
        x = a + (i * h);
        F1 = 9 + cos(x);
        F2 = sin(x) * cos(x);
        F3 = 14 * sin(x);
        printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------|\n|   %+.5f   |   %+.5f   |     %+.5f     |   %+.5f   |\n", x, F1, F2, F3);
    }
    printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------|\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    printf(...|   %+.5f   |   %+.5f   |     %+.5f     |   %+9.5f  |\n", x, F1, F2, F3);
```

должно вас спасти... (Для краткости выбросил кусок, главное - в `%+9.5f` и на один пробел меньше после него.)

Comment: Действительно помогло! Объясните, пожалуйста, почему именно 9?

Comment: Да потому что у вас самый большой вывод, который вам мешал - именно 9 символов. Вот я и сделал таким вывод всех чисел :)

Comment: Эта 9 в спецификации формата называется -- `"ширина поля"` (и тогда все становится понятным)

Comment: Про ширину поля знал, но только в общем. Теперь все ясно! Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте символы табуляции. Всё будет выравнено автоматически даже при других значениях:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

float a = -M_PI, b = M_PI/2, h = 0, x = 0;
float F1 = 0, F2 = 0, F3 = 0, i = 0;
int n = 7;

h = (b-a)/n;        // h = 0.673198
printf(" _______________________________________________________________\n|Single\t\tvariable\tfunctions\t\t\t|\n|---------------------------------------------------------------|\n|Argument\t|9+COS(X)\t|SIN(X)COS(X)\t|14SIN(X)\t|\n");
for (i = 0; i<=n; i++){
    x = a + (i * h);
    F1 = 9 + cos(x);
    F2 = sin(x) * cos(x);
    F3 = 14 * sin(x);
    printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------|\n|%+.5f\t|%+.5f\t|%+.5f\t|%+.5f\t|\n", x, F1, F2, F3);}
printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
return 0;}
```